# make-instance conses 524k bytes and takes 4msec

Tags: common-lisp

```
(time (make-instance 'Flat-Key :key "hello world" :fragment 1))
```

Yields:

```
Evaluation took:  
  0.005 seconds of real time  
  0.004367 seconds of total run time (0.004333 user, 0.000034 system)  
  80.00% CPU  
  22 lambdas converted  
  11,382,613 processor cycles  
  524,032 bytes consed

#<FLAT-KEY ((:KEY "hello world") (:HASH 1308457856027851121) (:BUCKET-INDEX 7)
        (:HASH-AS-MASK "1228937CD01BF9-7-1")) {10045AB573}>
```

Are these amounts normal?
If not, how can I improve my code?
If normal, what causes this?

The second and third call to `#'time` in in ±2.5msec and still cons ±500k bytes (second call had `#'print-object` method removed).

I'm using SBCL in a Emacs-slime session.  The class definition has 4 slots.  `#'print-object` does some work; i.e. it formats the lazily calculated hash).  But even with `#'print-object` removed it takes 2ms and conses ±500k bytes.
  The class and its functions are loaded via quicklisp's `quickload` (i'm not sure whether quicklisp has compiled the code or not; slime's `slime-compile-file` has no effect on speed or bytes consed).

`Flat-Key` is:

```
(defclass Flat-Key (Key)
  ()
  (:documentation
   "Keys without any level of nesting as used in conventional hash-tries and
Prokopecs CTrie."))
```

`Key` is:

```
(defclass Key ()
  ((val :initarg :key
    :reader get-key
    :documentation
    "The value of this Key")
   (hash :initarg :hash
     :initform nil
     :documentation
     "Cached `sxhash` of `key-val`, when nil it can be calculated.")
   (hash-fragment-index :initarg :fragment
            :reader get-fragment-index
            :documentation
            "The level in the trie for which `bucket-index` is valid.")
   (bucket-index :initform nil
         :documentation
         "Cached index into the `CNode's` `Bitindexed-List`."))
  (:documentation
   "Common base of all keys in a Trie"))
```

In Didier Verna *CLOS Efficiency: Instantiation: On the Behavior and Performance of Lisp, Part 2.1* International Lisp Conference ILC 2009, Mar 2009, Cambridge, United States. Proceedings of theILC 2009 Conference, 2009.  (available via https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01543396/document), Didier Verna measures millions of `#'make-instance' invocations in this timespan.

[CLOS make-instance is really slow and causes heap exhaustion in SBCL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27096007/814206) is also about `#'make-instance` and the amount of conses, but it appears [nrz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310991/nrz) is doing way more advanced stuff.  And I don't think I can apply [Rainer Joswig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69545/rainer-joswig)'s advice in my situation.

### tl; dr

Is it normal that `#'make-instance` with a 4 slot class takes 2ms-5ms and conses 400k-500k bytes?
If not, what am I doing wrong?
If normal, what is happening?

Comment: The first make-instance can have an overhead if it needs to call finalize-inheritance. You may want to call that yourself to factor out this overhead from subsequent calls.

Comment: Also, Slime/swank needs to exchange data and in an idle Lisp with Slime, the dynamic-space-usage slowly increases over time (and shrinks after each gc). That does not happen with a non-slimed environment. I don't think it should impact much "time", but you never know. Call gc before measuring. Try with a lot of invocations to get a statistically meaningful result.

Comment: Also put the code in a compiled function, rather than writing it directly to the REPL. While the REPL does compile the input form, SBCL doesn't optimize it the same way it does for functions.

Comment: Benchmarking a single call is likely to give unreliable results if the function is fast. Why not compile a function to make an instance `n` times and find a value of `n` to give you about 5s execution time or so, then look at the average.

Comment: @DanRobertson I grouped those comments in a community answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @jkiiski I grouped those comments in a community answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

*This is a community answer that regroup various comments. You can contribute to this answer and add other advices about benchmarking, not necessarily specific to SBCL.*

- Benchmarking a single call is likely to give unreliable results if the function is fast. Why not compile a function to make an instance N times and find a value of N to give you about 5s execution time or so, then look at the average. (Dan Robertson)
- Also put the code in a compiled function, rather than writing it directly to the REPL. While the REPL does compile the input form, SBCL doesn't optimize it the same way it does for functions. (jkiiski)
- The first [`make-instance`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_ins.htm) can have an overhead if it needs to call [`finalize-inheritance`](http://metamodular.com/CLOS-MOP/finalize-inheritance.html). You may want to call that yourself to factor out this overhead from subsequent calls.
- Note that by calling `(sb-ext:gc :full t)` before [`time`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_time.htm), you generally have less variance in results, removing one source of "noise" in your measures.
- Slime/swank needs to exchange data and in an idle Lisp with Slime, the [dynamic-space-size](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Function-sb_002dext-dynamic_002dspace_002dsize) slowly increases over time (and shrinks after each gc). That does not happen with a non-slimed environment. It might not impact much `time`, but you never know.